# How to hook empties to points of a curve programmatically?

Tags: modifiers

Here is a sample code which creates a primitive bezier spline (location1 and 2 are the control points' location):

```
def createBezierCurve(location1, location2):
    dirVect = getNormalizedDirVector(convertDictCoordToTuple(tableCenterCoords), convertDictCoordToTuple(refTableCenterCoords))
    bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_curve_add()
    obj = bpy.context.object
    obj.data.dimensions = '3D'
    obj.data.fill_mode = 'FULL'
    obj.data.bevel_depth = 0.02
    obj.data.bevel_resolution = 12

    obj.data.splines[0].bezier_points[0].co = location1
    obj.data.splines[0].bezier_points[0].handle_left = addVectors(location1, dirVect)
    obj.data.splines[0].bezier_points[0].handle_right = subtractVectors(location1, dirVect)
    obj.data.splines[0].bezier_points[0].handle_left_type = 'VECTOR'

    empty1 = bpy.data.objects.new("EmptyObject", None)
    empty1.location = location1
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(empty1)
    hookmod1 = obj.data.splines[0].bezier_points[0].modifiers.new("Hook", type='HOOK')
    hookmod1.object = empty1

    obj.data.splines[0].bezier_points[1].co = location2
    obj.data.splines[0].bezier_points[1].handle_left = addVectors(location2, dirVect)
    obj.data.splines[0].bezier_points[1].handle_right = subtractVectors(location2, dirVect)
    obj.data.splines[0].bezier_points[1].handle_left_type = 'VECTOR'

    empty2 = bpy.data.objects.new("EmptyObject", None)
    empty2.location = location2
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(empty2)
    hookmod2 = obj.data.splines[0].bezier_points[1].modifiers.new("Hook", type='HOOK')
    hookmod2.object = empty2
```

What I couldn't find is how to hook the points to these empties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To add a hook modifier**

Following code adds a hook modifier. named *Hook1*,  to the curve object `CurveOB` and sets the hook object to `Empty1`

```
hookmod = curveOB.modifiers.new("Hook1", type='HOOK')
hookmod.object = empty1
```

Comment: (Take in consideration that I'm very new to Blender)

Okay, but how can I hook to a vertex of a curve, not the whole curve? How can I "get" a curve object's vertex?

Comment: I "revised" my idea, and I got to the point where I know have to code this: First select 1 of the 2 control points of a bezier_point (https://i.imgur.com/ocuPq9G.png), then "Hook to a New Object" (https://i.imgur.com/ClG4dQC.png). Could you edit your code so it can work? I edit my code, but of course it doesn't work because it throws "AttributeError: 'BezierSplinePoint' object has no attribute 'modifiers'" error.

Comment: In your new code above: Use `obj.modifiers.new(...)` , where `obj` is the curve object created via operator.  The modifiers collection (`obj.modifiers`) is on the curve object, not the bezier point of the curve objects data.  Setting the location of the empty  positions the hook.  Suggest your method above `return obj, empty1, empty2`

Comment: .. oh and give them a different name otherwise blender will auto name the second `"Hook.0001"`  Finally, could use the _Hook to New Object_ operator, but off top of my head - without checking, will need to be run with the curve in edit mode. As a rule of thumb try avoiding operators when an API method is available.